# IN ECHO statement how can i print all the columns without defining multiple output parameters

Tags: batch-file, echo

```
for /f  " tokens=%i%-%j% delims=," %%a in (%input%) DO ( 
(ECHO %%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f %%g %%h %%i %%j)>>%output%
)
```

Comment: may there be empty fields (like missing "gamma" in `alpha|beta||delta|epsilon...`)?

Answer (score 0):

`"delims="` will force no delimiter and use full string making each line `%%a` instead of each word, delimited by `,`.

```
for /f  "delims=" %%a in (%input%) DO ECHO %%a >>%output%
```

If you would like to get rid of the `,` simply replace it.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f  "delims=" %%a in (%input%) DO ( set string=%%a
set string=!string: =,!
ECHO !string! >> %output%
)
endlocal
```

Comment: but as part of my requirement i want to add delimiter between each column. but i dont want to do it like (ECHO %%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f %%g %%h %%i %%j ). because there maybe chances to get more columns or less columns.. is there anyother way to print without hardcoding the parameter (%%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f %%g %%h %%i %%j)

Comment: @NareshKumar I just showed you how.. have you tried my code? You are not adding any delimiter at all, only spaces, you are splitting by , using delims.

Comment: Please add the example data of your input and also show expected result by editing your Question

Comment: Input file text :IDR 15401012017102412483000001871201962841841         02392259906         1      MX1 2027              2026             000000000C  5                            ORIGC02392259906
OUTPUT :IDR,15401012017102412483000001871201962841841,02392259906,1,MX1,2027,2026,000000000C,5,ORIGC02392259906

Comment: One of those moments. Have you tried my code? Also, when posting examples and code, please add it to your question by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48503272/edit) it

Comment: instead of space i have to add comma as a delimiter for all the rows which is there in file. but column number may differs for each file. so i should create this file in a generic manner to print

Comment: @Stephan Yes, thanks. I actually forgot to remove it from his copied code.

Comment: @Gerhard Barnard, yea .. tried and i got a output like below
IDR,15401012017102412483000001871201962841841,02392259906,1,MX1,2027,2026,000000000C,5,ORIGC02392259906,,,,,,,,,

Comment: ok, so that is what you expected, right? obviously the multiple `,` at the end is there because it found whitespace in the original file, you said there can be more or less columns per row.

Comment: i dont want to print the empty token value.. if you saw at the end ,,,,,, is coming..please help on that..

Comment: ok, that changes the scope completely, how to cater then for columns that have empty values? if you have column headers it will break the data completely.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard: [yes, but...](http://www.lovethispic.com/uploaded_images/47453-Monday-Only-Happens-Once-A-Week.jpg)

Comment: @GerhardBarnard, Thanks for the code.. it is working..  having small question.. i got output like (IDR,15401012017102412483000001871201962841841,,,,,02392259906,,,,,1,,,MX1,2027,,,,,,,2026,,,,,,,000000000C,5,,,,,,,,,,,,,,ORIGC02392259906)
is there any way to restrict or change multiple comma as single comma?

Comment: @NareshKumar: are you sure, you want that?

Comment: Yes there is. See @stephan answer

Comment: usually, the problem is to *keep* multiple delimiters. Reducing multiple delimiters to one doesn't cause any headache.

Comment: @NareshKumar Will the columns ever have headers? If yes, then removing the extra commas will not work, if not it can be done,  but the data structure will be busted.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments, the following should do exactly, what you want: multiple spaces are reduced to one delimiter, no delimiters at the end of a line.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(for /f "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do (
  set "new="
  for %%b in (%%a) do (
    set "new=!new!,%%b"
  )
  echo !new:~1!
))>output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your `?` characters may be problematic with some solutions, the following may do what you require:

```bat
@Echo Off

Set "input=input.txt"
Set "output=output.txt"

Set "_="
(For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("%input%"
) Do Set "_="&Call :Sub %%A&Call Echo(%%_:~1%%)>"%output%"
If Not Defined _ Del "%output%"
Exit /B

:Sub
If "%1"=="" GoTo :EOF
Set "_=%_%,%1"
Shift&GoTo :Sub
```